# Android Sweet Alert Dialog dependencies

Tags: android, github, gradle

I read [Sweet AlertDialog](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1065) tutorial and I have added dependencies to my project this way:

1. select Build.Gradle (Module:app) and open
2. go to this line:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   }
   ```

   and change to:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
   }
   ```
3. Run the my app.but i get this error:

   ```
   Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
      > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0.
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0/appcompat-v7-21.0.0.pom
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0/appcompat-v7-21.0.0.jar
            file:/D:/sdk/ADT-Bundle-Windows-x86-20140702.Full_p30download.com/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0/appcompat-v7-21.0.0.pom
            file:/D:/sdk/ADT-Bundle-Windows-x86-20140702.Full_p30download.com/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0/appcompat-v7-21.0.0.jar
            file:/D:/sdk/ADT-Bundle-Windows-x86-20140702.Full_p30download.com/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0/appcompat-v7-21.0.0.pom
            file:/D:/sdk/ADT-Bundle-Windows-x86-20140702.Full_p30download.com/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0/appcompat-v7-21.0.0.jar
        Required by:
            MyApplication:app:unspecified > cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3 > com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.0
   ```

And when i add `appcompat-v7-21.0.0.jar` i get this error:

```
Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0
<a href="openFile">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Open in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Comment: I got the same error. I have no clue how to fix. Why is Android so convoluted. :/

Answer (score 0):

Remove appcompat-v7-21.0.0.jar first, then try replace your dependencies with the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
}
```

Comment: write your code and i get this error:Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3.

         > repo.jfrog.org
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3.
     Required by:
         MyApplication:app:unspecified > cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3 > com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.0
      > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.pom'.
         > repo.jfrog.org

Answer (score 0):

If its a case of missing support library, I think you need to download **Android Support Repository** from the

Android SDK Manager->SDK Tools->Support Repository->Android Support Repository.